# Microsoft Dynamics AX 2009 development

Tags: axapta, x++

I'm new to Microsoft Dynamics AX development and I'd like to learn basic things about it.
I have a virtual machine with the '09 version installed.

Is it essential to get familiarized with the language (X++) from the beginning?
What should I start with (tutorials, videos, overviews, guided tours) and where do I find it?

I'd like links, tips, or anything that may help!

Is it easy to find step by step tutorials? Any links for that?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Because SO does not let me to post many links I have posted it to [Axaptapedia](http://www.axaptapedia.com/Beginner's_information)

Download the "Inside Dynamics Ax 4" free ebook from microsoft and read then read What's new about changes in Ax2009 (X++ is pretty the same)

Some other cool resources:
axaptapedia
code.msdn.microsoft.com/axcodesamples

Paper Books :

Inside Dynamics Ax 2009
Managing supply chain using Dynamics Ax 2009

Is you have access to partnersource or customer source, go there and [read development](http://www.microsoft.com/learning/en/us/course.aspx?ID=8623A&Locale=en-us) and financial trainings

Comment: I do have access to partnersource, where exactly should i get in to read it ? (i'm new in this company)

Comment: I edited my post since you have access to PartnerSource and there are lots of information there.

Comment: Excuse me, for sime technical reasons I do not have access to PartnerSOurce, so I can not point a menu item for info. 

There are several of trainings named "Development I" to  "Development IV" - and read at least Financials trainings to be famniliar with functionality.

Answer (score 8):

You have a nice starting point in the free book:

http://www.lulu.com/morphxit

It is from 2006 but the basics works those days. When you are familiar with the environment I can recommend the "Inside Dynamics AX" books (versions 4 or 2009) from Microsoft Press. Those are impressive books from the AX development staff directly.

Microsoft Development Center has lots of information (videos!) for developers:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics/ax/default.aspx

If you know C# or Java you are not going to experience many problems with the language, it is all to be fluent in the MorphX environment, that onesty, is way easy in it's basis, but you have to work and fight with lots and lots of standard classes. That is, for my experience, the most dificult part of AX learning. Easy part, is that almost every one of those classes are docummented somewhere.

If you have PartnerSource access, in the learning  & certification menu you have access to the materials of the official courses. There are 4 progressive courses of developing and those are a very nice starting point if you have access to it.

http://www.microsoft.com/learning/en/us/certification/dynamics-ax-professional.aspx#dev2009

Here you can find all the certification Exams, and inside each of them, you can find the course code. With this codes you can searh inside PartnerSource to find the appropiate materials of the courses.

Answer (score 6):

This is a good place to start:

[Developer Portal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics/ax/default.aspx)

For more advanced information the Microsoft press inside Dynamics AX books are very good.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that unless you are developing the kernel, all customization and extension is done via X++. The language itself is a bit like C++ but it has some syntactic sugar for SQL queries and such.

I guess a good starting point is http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa867122.aspx

PS: When I worked there, there was a big push for C# so that's probably a good thing to explore.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to start doing the things in the right way, coding always with the Best Practices on your mind. 
 The  white paper *Top Development Best Practices for Microsoft Dynamics AX 2009* [1](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=0AD62EE4-B87F-4D71-8B69-BFB7C1F36BA4&displaylang=en&displaylang=en)  was released last month and cover a lot of interesting topics for a developer