# Microsoft Dynamics AX - Resources for new developers

Tags: .net, axapta

I am trying to find some good resources that will help me understand how to use the [.NET Business Connector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb496526.aspx) and without digging too deep into X++ and those other AX-specific things.

First of all I want a bit more knowledge regarding the very AX usage basics and after that I want to head on to the AX for .NET developers.

So, suggestions on books and resources for this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Microsoft Dynamics AX 2009 development](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1948029/microsoft-dynamics-ax-2009-development)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I can give you some links.
Remember to google both AX and the former name Axapta.

AX in general:

- http://www.axaptapedia.com/Main_Page

.Net/AX:

- http://www.axaptapedia.com/.NET_Integration

Books:

- http://www.axaptapedia.com/Books
- http://www.lulu.com/morphxit

Microsoft:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc678142.aspx
- http://www.microsoft.com/dynamics/en/us/partner-login.aspx
- http://www.microsoft.com/dynamics/en/us/using/ax-using.aspx

Comment: Thank you, I will check them out!

Answer (score 1):

AX 2012 for c# devs:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc967357.aspx