# Want to learn MS Dynamics(Confused between ERP and CRM)

Tags: dynamics-crm, axapta, dynamics-gp, dynamics-nav

I am confused about MS Dynamics.I am having 7 years of experience in MS technology (asp.net, C#, vb.net, Sql 2005/2008, WCF, SharePoint 3.0) and Crystal report 10.0.

I want to learn MS Dynamics but unable to know which to choose interms of better job opertunity(ERP or CRM) and more specifically(GP/NAV/AX).

Please help me to choose a course structure and tell me the time frame required to learn. I can spend 2 hours every day on learning, more on week ends.

Answer (score 1):

GP, NAV and AX are different products, so learning one will not teach you much of the others.
You cannot meaningful learn MS Dynamics, you will have to choose.

Regarding ERP and CRM: google the definitions. ERP is broad, CRM is narrow.

AX ressources, have a look here: [Microsoft Dynamics AX - Resources for new developers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2713410/microsoft-dynamics-ax-resources-for-new-developers)