# General quesions about Dynamics Ax

Tags: x++, axapta, ax

I'm a newbie in Dynamics Ax and have mountains of quesions:

*What computer programmering language do you use to code new functionality in Ax? Is it C#?

*When you do some coding, does it take place in Visual studio 2010?

*If ERP use C# as a coding lanuage, is it C# from winform or Windows presentation foundation?

*What is the main standard of IT architecture that Ax is using when you start implementing it in a company? N-tier with presentation, business and data layer?

*Does Dynamics have build in Microsoft Business Intelligence?

*What object-relational mapping (ORM) framework does it use to retrieve data from data layer to the presentation layer? Entity framework, Nhibernate, Dataset?

*If a customer has three database tool that is SQL server, Oracle and MySQL and these need to be used in Dynamics Ax, does  Ax has a tool in order to combine these database and its data into one unit? Maybe you need to use SSIS etc.

// Fullmetalboy

Answer (score 6):

It's not a good idea to ask more than 1 question in SO but there we go:

- Language is X++ (propietary language, only available in AX) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa867122.aspx
- Before 2012 version it has it's own editor. In AX 2012 you can code something from VS but mainly you have to work in the native editor.
- It's not C#, it's X++ http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc967357.aspx
- AX has its own architecture. You can find more info about that on MSDN. All layers are integrated and you can't change that behaviour.
- It can be integrated natively with Microsoft Analysis Services, and throw SQL server with all other BI systems you want.
- AX has it's own framework. All the developer environment is a framework itself.
- You can only install AX with SQL Server or Oracle (before 2012 version).

All of those are very basic questions than you can answer easilly in the oficial AX documentation:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa496080.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Reading a general introduction to AX would help. The answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1948029/microsoft-dynamics-ax-2009-development) applies.

Very basic facts may be found [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Dynamics_AX). Most of your questions may be answered by Google search.

Sorry, asking more than one question in StackOverflow is [not recommended](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39223/one-post-with-multiple-questions-or-multiple-posts).